# JUnit test with Spring and mongodb: could not autowire repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, junit4, spring-mongo

I have problem writing a test with Spring and JUnit to test a MongoDB respository. The message is "could not autowire. No beans of ... type found"
My repository is

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Project, String> {

public Project findByName(String name);

}
```

while my configuration file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = RepositoryPackage.class)
public class SpringMongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{


@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "test";
}

@Bean
public MongoClient mongo() throws Exception {

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost");
    return client;
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), getDatabaseName());
}

}
```

where RepositoryPackage is in the same package of the repository. 
My test is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringMongoConfiguration.class)
public class MongoDbProjectTests {

@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

@Before
public void init(){

    projectRepository.deleteAll();
    Project project = new Project("sdfjklgh", 1, "comunione Leonardo",
            Project.TYPE_PROJECT_PHOTO, Project.STATE_PROJECT_DRAFT);

    projectRepository.save(project);
}

@Test
public void test1(){
    List<Project> list = projectRepository.findAll();
    assertEquals(1, list.size());
}

}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a project and copied your files into it, and it works for me.

The only cause that I can guess is that your `ProjectRepository` class is not in the same package as your `RepositoryPackage` class that you specify as the `basePackageClasses` attribute for component-scanning. (It should also be okay if `ProjectRepository` is in a package inside the package that `RepositoryPackage` is in.)

I've published the project to [GitHub](https://github.com/matthew-pearson/SOMongoJunit), but it uses Gradle rather than Maven.

And now [another one](https://github.com/matthew-pearson/SOMongoJunitMaven/), this time using Maven.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?